# Symfony3 environment base settings

Tags: symfony

I am using Symfony3 for quite while now. Today I am at the point where I need to store different api hosts per environment.

Like:

```
Development
Staging
Production
```

I tried to put these settings in config.ymal, but symfony faild to parse it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance.

Danyal

Comment: Read [How to Organize Configuration Files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/configuration_organization.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put them in the config file of the environment
Like :

```
in config_dev.yml:
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
ip:     "127.0.0.1"

in config_env1.yml:
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
ip:     "192.58.56.46"

in config.yml:
ip: "%ip%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file like for exemple `config_stagging.yml` and add

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
```

Add scpecific configuration you want inside the file

Copy `app_dev.php` to `app_stagging.php`

Change line `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);` to `$kernel = new AppKernel('stagging', true);`

Execut command : `php bin/console cache:clear`

In your url inside to use `app_dev`, use `app_stagging`

Answer (score 1):

either of the above answers are fine.

But another approach would be to have a `parameters.yml` file per server install, and have the server dependent settings in there.  This is how symfony ships.

It avoids the need to have separate front end controllers set up which I prefer as it keeps things simple.

Make sure `parameters.yml` is added to `.gitIgnore`, and also make sure that the `parameters.yml.dist` file contains the same entries in it (or delete the fine entirely), otherwise when you run composer it'll delete any entries that don't match it.